# JSON mapping and validating a map structure into list of Pairs in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, type-conversion, payload

I'm trying to parse the following JSON payload:

```
{
"a": "b",
"b": "c",
"d": "e",
}
```

I have my controller method like this:

```
@Post("/items")
fun items(@Body myMap : Map<String, String>) {
    println(myMap)
}
```

and it works as expected but I would like to validate the payload and generate this map on my own.
Actually I would like to have something like this:

```
@Post("/items")
fun items(@Body myMap :  List<Pair<String, String>>) {
    println(myMap)
}
```

If I change @Body type, I get:

```
"errors": [
 {"message": "Failed to convert argument [pairs] for value [null] due to: Instantiation of [simple type, class kotlin.Pair<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>] value failed for JSON property first due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter first which is a non-nullable type\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[0]->kotlin.Pair[\"first\"])",
                "path": "/pairs"
}
```

Any Idea how to convert this payload into list of Pairs?

Best regards

Comment: Well your body isn't a list, so I'd be surprised if your deserializer were to automatically deserialize it to a list. You just write a custom deserializer that can handle your body and gives your output format. How this is done in code depends on your http server framework and json deserializer, neither of which you mentioned in the question.
Based on your error it also sounds like your deserializer doesn't know how to create a kotlin Pair, you will need to fix that as well (eg. for jackson load in the kotlin module).

Comment: @somethingsomething thanks for your answer. so I'm using micronaut 3.5.2 as framework and jackson 2.13.2 com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin